# Oracle SQL - Creating Multiple Ranges for Date Possibilities in a Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query:

```
Select * 
From Player_Chkin_Cs
```

That spits out the result:

```
Player_ID     CS_ID   CS_LISTING_ID  CS_COMP_NAME   PT_ADD  CREATE_DTIME   UUID
 179364        300      60132          Wilshire       3      22-DEC-10     (null)
 179364        320      68968          Wilshire       30     28-JAN-10     (null)
 132489        200      55168          Wilshire       13     03-Jan-10     (null)
 132489        900      65478          Wilshire       23     15-Feb-10     (null)
```

I want to create a query that returns the player_ids of only players who have create_dtimes that fall in both the ranges of 01-Dec-10 to 31-Dec-10 AND 01-Jan-10 to 31-Jan-10.(aka only Player_ID 179364 would show up in the results of this example)

Please let me know if you have any suggestions!

Comment: `select distinct player_id from table where trunc(create_Dtime) between '01-Dec-10' AND 31-Dec-10 OR trunc(create_Dtime) between '01-Jan-10' AND '31-Jan-10';`

Comment: Annjawn, wouldn't I want select player_id from table where trunc(create_Dtime) between '01-Dec-10' AND 31-Dec-10 AND trunc(create_Dtime) between '01-Jan-10' AND '31-Jan-10', instead of or, if the player_id had to have both to qualify?

Comment: No, Create_datetime for one row/record cannot satisfy both the conditions, so using `AND` would never return anything. example- 22-DEC-10 cannot be in both the ranges, which the query would try to do in case if you use `AND`. Try for yourself :)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But in your case if player 179364 had a create_dtime that was between 01-dec-10 and 31-dec-10 and did not have a create_dtime in the range of 01-jan-10 to 31-jan-10, they would still be included in the results if I used or, wouldn't they?

Comment: Ok, so you would want the id of the player who are in both the ranges? is that correct? i guess i misunderstood the question

Comment: Apologize if wasn't clear to start. Yes, I would want the id of the players who are in both the ranges.

Comment: Annjawn-- Is it possible to get what I am looking for in Oracle SQL?

Comment: sure it is. Just look at Justin Cave's answer, his query should be able to do the work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be

```
SELECT player_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT trunc(create_dtime, 'MM')) num_months
  FROM player_chkin_cs
 WHERE trunc(create_dtime,'MM') IN (date '2010-12-01', date '2010-01-01')
 GROUP BY player_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT trunc(create_dtime, 'MM')) = 2
```

Comment: hmm this doesnt seem to want to provide a result. Does '2010-12-01' mean dec 1 only, or does that include any item labeled with MM '12' and YYYY '2010'?

Comment: @Stuav - `date '2010-12-01'` is December 1, 2010.  However `trunc(create_dtime,'MM')` will truncate all dates to the first of the month.  So any `create_date` that occurred some time in December of 2010 will get truncated to December 1, 2010.